# How to vertically align text in a header bar

Tags: html, css

As you can see by this codepen even if I set 
`text-align: center;` the image is right, but the text is on the bottom. How do I make it vertically aligned to the middle of the image.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  test
  <img src="../immagini/logo.png" height="100px" style="padding: 0px 20px">test
</div>
```

Comment: the image is broken for now

Answer (score 1):

This is ridiculously easy.
Just use this:

```
img {
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: Fast on a keyboard :)

Comment: Of course, there isn't any real figuring out an answer, it's that simple. It's just who sees it first and who is "fastest on the keyboard".

Comment: The ability to touch type is one of a developers best friends!

Comment: ticka tacka ticka tacka ticka tack